# Is it possible to use a Conv2D layer without a model or a running Session?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm writing an article about Conv2D nets and I want to preview the effect of a Conv2D net on an image, I could get this using a simple keras model and getting the output of first layer (which is the conv), but I wanted a simpler way.

So I did this:

```
layer = Conv2D(10, (3, 3), input_shape=[1080, 1080, 3])
tensor_in = tf.convert_to_tensor(img, dtype="float")
tensor_out = layer(tensor_in)
```

The code above works fine and I end up with a tensor `tensor_out`.
**The problem is** I couldn't manage to read the data from this tensor. 
is there anyway to do it without having to use the `.eval()` function that requires a running session?

Comment: If you want do display it as an image you need to evaluate it inside session. You could also visualize using tensorboard. Is visualization is what you're after?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. But to be honest it kinda bugs me that I can't simply extract a value of a layer simply by running a tensor through only that layer. I mean tensorflow has all the methods built in, it's theoretically doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to avoid sessions is to use eager execution:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

Note that you need to enable it before using any TF ops! Now, TF ops are evaluated as they are defined. In your example you can use

```
layer = Conv2D(10, (3, 3), input_shape=[1080, 1080, 3])
tensor_in = tf.convert_to_tensor(img, dtype="float")
tensor_out = layer(tensor_in)
result = tensor_out.numpy()
```

to get a numpy array for further processing. For more information on eager execution read [the basic tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager) and/or [the guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) on the TF website.

Comment: That's pretty much it! Thanks a bunch. Although I still hate that I simply can't get the output of a layer by simply feeding it a tensor. I'm new to tensorflow anyway, i'll play around with the code more, because i think i'm missing what a session really is